# Synonymize [gdocs]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

There's [gdocs](/questions/tagged/gdocs) around with about 20 questions, all about Google documents. I propose to make it a synonyme to [google-docs](/questions/tagged/google-docs) which has more than 1000 questions and better fits the `google-[whatever]` schema.